# Group by and aggregate the columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate

I have following dataframe which I would like to group by a certain column and aggregate the uniques values in other column of respective row by a separator like ' | '. Below is the sample rows:

```
col1                                                col2            col3                col4
THREE M SYNDROME 1  {3-M syndrome 1, 273750 (3)}    3-m syndrome 1  {3-M syndrome 1}    273750
THREE M SYNDROME 1  {3-M syndrome 1, 273750 (3)}    3-m syndrome 2  {3-M syndrome 2}    273750
```

I would like to group by 'col1' and aggregate the other unique values. The expected df is:

```
col1                                                col2            col3                       col4
THREE M SYNDROME 1  {3-M syndrome 1, 273750 (3)}    3-m syndrome 1 | 3-m syndrome 2 {3-M syndrome 1} | {3-M syndrome 2} 273750
```

I am using following lines of code.

```
join_unique = lambda x: ' | '.join(x.unique())
df2= df.groupby(['preferred_title_symbol'], as_index=False).agg(join_unique)
```

I get output but col4 is not included in the output.

```
col1                                                col2            col3                       
THREE M SYNDROME 1  {3-M syndrome 1, 273750 (3)}    3-m syndrome 1 | 3-m syndrome 2 {3-M syndrome 1} | {3-M syndrome 2}
```

Any help is highly  appreciated.

Comment: As you have a non-canonical DataFrame, please provide a constructor for clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be because col4 contains integers, therefore the join doesn't work. You could try with an if/else like this:

```
data = {'col1': {0: 'THREE M SYNDROME 1  {3-M syndrome 1, 273750 3)}',
  1: 'THREE M SYNDROME 1  {3-M syndrome 1, 273750 (3)}'},
 'col2': {0: '3-m syndrome 1', 1: '3-m syndrome 2'},
 'col3': {0: '{3-M syndrome 1}', 1: '{3-M syndrome 2}'},
 'col4': {0: 273750, 1: 273750}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

>>> df.groupby('col1').agg(lambda x: ' | '.join(x.unique()) if x.nunique()>1 else x.unique()[0]   )

Out:

                                                col2    col3    col4
col1            
THREE M SYNDROME 1 {3-M syndrome 1, 273750 (3)} 3-m syndrome 1 | 3-m syndrome 2 {3-M syndrome 1} | {3-M syndrome 2} 273750
```